# Как сохранить 16 бит в файл

Tags: c++, c, файлы

Допустим если я открою текстовый файл и сохраню туда число 65535, то он будет весть 5 байт, но данное число можно в битах выразить как 1111111111111111, и в битах это всего 2 байта, так вот как сохранить данное число в файл, что бы это было 2 байта и потом можно его извлечь из битов... Вообщем как сохранить биты в файл?

Comment: Зачем указывать 3 разных языка программирования в метках?

Comment: @bsbak Вам может и все равно на каком языке. А вот тем, кто потом будет искать на данном сайте ответ - может быть не все равно. И он найдет отвеченный вопрос по интересующей его тематике по языку golang и к его глубокому сожалению принятый ответ он увидит на языке C, т.е. ответ ему не подойдет. Так что раз указали такой тег, то пожалуйста переведите на golang данный вам ответ и напишите его тут. что бы в будущем люди могли найти правильный ответ по подходящим им тегам

Comment: Мне важно и принципиально, чтобы вопрос был задан корректно. Я вижу 2 допустимых формулировки вопроса: a) вы хотите получить ответ для конкретного языка программирования б) вы хотите сравнить способы реализации чтения/записи в бинарный файл для 2-ух или более ЯП. В первом случае нужна 1 метка, для 2-ого - могут пополнятся вместе с ответами. Своим комментарием я хотел прояснить 'категорию' вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте *бинарный* режим работы с файлом и соответствующие функции записи.

Например, для `FILE`:

```
unsigned short i = 65535;
FILE * f = fopen("file","wb");
fwrite(&i,sizeof(i),1,f);
fclose(f);

unsigned short n;
FILE * g = fopen("file","rb");
fread(&n,sizeof(n),1,f);
fclose(f);
```

Для `fstream`'ов - открывать с флагом `ios::bianary` и использовать функции `write` и `read`.